# PHP Google Adwords API V201402 + Daily Click for generating chart

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I want to generate chart with respect to Clicks Vs Date.

I am using Adwords API V201402.

How can i generate chart like attached screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So there are many ways this could be accomplished.  From my experience, I have actually done similar reporting utilizing PHP and **Google Visualization charts**.  You would probably want a single Area Chart:  [https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#area_chart](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#area%5fchart).  I'm sure you can get it to look pretty close to the Google Analytics report you displayed above.  You are going to have to utilize some `javascript` skills, but they are at most beginner level if you follow the samples provided by Google.